# How to finish an activity from RecyclerView adapter class using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin programming language and I want to finish my RecyclerView activity from adapter class. How do I do it?
It used to be quite easy in java but I just switched to Kotlin and I am facing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create this method in the activity:

```
fun finishMe() { finish() }
```

In your adapter declare this:

```
private val activity : MainActivity = context as MainActivity
```

replace `MainActivity` with the activity's name and `context` is the activity's `Context` passed to the adapter as a parameter (I believe it exists). 
Now you can finish the activity anywhere in the adapter by:

```
activity.finishMe()
```

Answer (score 4):

> you can use `finish()` method ,

```
(context as YourActivity).finish()
```

this method will help you to finish the respective activity.

Comment: @muhammad-faizan hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `((Activity)context).finish();` in java than in kotlin you can use `(context as Activity).finish()`

Try it.